# ORACLE SQL - How to create a new table with sorted rows from an existing table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a new table from an existing table containing Products, Distributorid, Stock and multiple other fields. I want the rows in the new table to be sorted based on the stock value with maximum stock value on the top.

Since table is huge. I'm inserting the data for one distributorid in one go. Following is the query used.

```
INSERT INTO STOCKTABLE2 
  SELECT * 
    from STOCKTABLE 
   where distributorid = '1' 
   ORDER BY stock desc;
```

The above query inserts the rows. However when I run a 'Select *' query, the products still come up in jumbled fashion instead of the products with maximum stock at the top. Could you please help ?

Comment: Ordering in a select is non-deterministic unless you are using an explicitly ordered index.  If you want ordered rows in a select, use the `ORDER BY` clause there instead of trying to order them on insert.

Comment: I agree with Michael, I dont understand the reason for creating one more table too.. directly you the first table

Comment: Would have appreciated if instead questioning the intent, you would have helped in providing a solution. Anyways, found a way from this other post -  i need to use INSERT /*+ append */ INTO ...

Comment: Rajat, I understand your frustration. However, Michael and Neha are not merely questioning intent here. Although​,   ordering is likely to be deterministic (same each time), and will be influenced by primary keys and other indexes, no matter how the data is organised in a table, when you select from it there are no guarantees about the order in which the data will be presented unless you specify an order by clause.  For that reason, adding an additional table really just replicates the 'problem' rather than providing a 'solution'.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (well, not documentation but an article from Oracle): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32sql-1541432.html

"Oracle Database table data isn’t stored in any specific order, regardless of the order in which it was inserted into the database. To retrieve rows in either ascending or descending order by column, you must tell the database that you want to do so."

...

"You retrieve sorted data by adding an ORDER BY clause to your SELECT statement. ORDER BY is always the last clause in a query."

Answer (score 0):

Found this from another post.
I need to use

```
INSERT /*+ append */ INTO TABLE2 SELECT * from TABLE1 where id = '1' ORDER BY stock desc
```

Comment: `Order by` in your solution only increases statement execution time.